# convert an large interface to an small interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an interface called **IHistoryData**

```
export interface IHistoryData {
    CourseId: string,
    CourseName: string,
    Duration: number,
    IsMandatory: boolean,
    CompetencyList: string[],
    IsActive:boolean
}
```

and a second small interface called ICurrentData,

```
export interface ICurrentData {
    CourseId: string,
    CourseName: string,
    Duration: number,
}
```

**ICurrentData** properties are subset of **IHistoryData** properties.

Now I am trying to convert a **IHistoryData[]** into **ICurrentData[]** using **ES6 destructing feature** but unable to find any working solution.
 Is it possible to convert a large interface into a small interface using destructing??

I am using TS 2.3.3 and angular 4.4

Comment: Thanks @Saran for edits.

Comment: There's nothing to convert. IHistoryData implements ICurrentData, so you can just do `const v2: ICurrentData[] = theArrayOfHistoryData;`. Or do you actually want to make a copy?

Comment: So I am currently filter data based on a flag in IHistoryData[] and dumping the result into ICurrentData[]. Currently I have these two interfaces seperate but I like your way of  inheriting larger interface from smaller interface. I will update my interface and test this. will update the outcome soon.

Comment: The larger one extends the smaller one de facto. But of course, if that's your intention, actually using `extends` would be cleaner.

Comment: You are so right. I have updated my interfaces to use inheritance and it works :) .  Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can destructure as part of the mapping, or you could just map... there isn't a huge amount of difference either way so choose what is most readable.

For all the examples, I'm using the source data in the variable `input`.

## Quick Type Change

If you just need to change the type, you don't actually need to map as you can assign the `input` to `ICurrentData[]` because it is a compatible type. The data technically still exists on input, but when you use `output` it will only autocomplete the the subset of properties.

```
const output: ICurrentData[] = input;
```

## Destructuring

Where the property names are the same, you can destructure like this...

```
const output: ICurrentData[] = input.map((history) => {
  const { CourseId, CourseName, Duration } = history;
  return {
    CourseId,
    CourseName,
    Duration
  };
});

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

## Negative Destructuring

You could also do a "negative destructuring" by listing the items you don't want to map in the destructuring assignment- and using a rest argument to grab everything you do want. It's a neat trick, but I don't like the coupling to "stuff you don't want". If you only need to eliminate one or two properties out of 20, it could be an option.

```
const output: ICurrentData[] = input.map((history) => {
  const { IsMandatory, CompetencyList, IsActive, ...data } = history;
  return data;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

## Different Property Names

If the source data has different names for the properties (for example, `A`, `B`, `C`) you can map that as part of the destructuring.

```
const output: ICurrentData[] = input.map((history) => {
  const { A: CourseId, B: CourseName, C: Duration } = history;
  return {
    CourseId,
    CourseName,
    Duration
  };
});

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

## Simple Map

Sometimes, simple is beautiful. This is a simple map, using the same properties as the previous example.

```
const output: ICurrentData[] = input.map((history) => {
  return {
    CourseId: history.A,
    CourseName: history.B,
    Duration: history.C
  };
});

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: an up-vote for your approach. although currently I do not need to use this approach but it is certainly useful if column names are not identical in smaller and large interface. Thanks !!